# Is it possible to build GMP with Clang 10 and LLVM?

Tags: arm, clang, cross-compiling, llvm-clang, gmp

I've been trying to build the gmp library so I can build GCC, but it fails to build with Clang. The only reason I am using Clang is because I am using LLVM-MinGW (https://github.com/mstorsjo/llvm-mingw). I want to build it for ARM. I have looked around and the most I can find is that it cannot build for iPhone's ARM system. It doesn't say anything about Windows or Linux. I'm trying to build with Linux, but I can use Windows if needed. I've gotten as far as building *some* with Linux. I get a little far in and then I get the error

`tmp-udiv.s:67:2: error: predicated instructions must be in IT block`
`subcs   r1, r1, r3`

I have to put the outputs on pastebin as they're too large for here. :)

My configure file gives the output here: https://pastebin.com/6AfrBjrj

And my makefile gives the output here: https://pastebin.com/YvG0iPfa

If it's not possible, oh well, but I would be very grateful if it is possible to and I could be told how to. The most I can find is this reference from 2014 (https://gmplib.org/list-archives/gmp-devel/2014-November/003859.html). That is from 2014 though, who knows how useful it is nowadays? My Linux distribution is Pop!_OS 20.04 if it is needed, up to date, and LLVM-MinGW is up to date too.
Any help is appreciated,
Thanks.

Comment: Do you realize how old gmp 4.3.2 is?

Comment: Yes, but when I tried building the latest version it also gave an error.
tmp-lshift.s:83:2: error: invalid instruction, any one of the following would fix this:
        orr     r7, r7, r6, lsr r12

Comment: I'm mainly just trying to build it to build GCC.

Comment: If you have trouble building the latest version directly, you should post details on the gmp-bugs mailing list.